# Could not find method compile() for arguments project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

When building my project with gradle, I get an error

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':common'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.



org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':core'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':common'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at build_7ik97bgumtntdjoan6kma2j39$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\core\build.gradle:6)
    at build_7ik97bgumtntdjoan6kma2j39.run(C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\core\build.gradle:1)
```

pointing to the line
https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/core/build.gradle#L9

core module https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/core/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
/*******************************
 * Compile Dependencies
 *******************************/

compile project(":common")
...
}
```

common module https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/common/build.gradle

I do not know why it can not compile the common module?

Comment: The Core module does not have the `java` plugin applied. It's done above, at the top level, here : https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/build.gradle#L35
How do you use the Core module ?

Comment: The ```core``` module is compiled in the ```web``` module https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/build.gradle#L9

Comment: And you directly use the web module ? Because this one does not apply the `java` plugin either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be in the [root *build.gradle* file](https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/build.gradle#L13):

```
def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll {
    it.name == "common" & it.name == "core" && it.name == "web"
}
```

This condition will never hold. That's because a subproject's name cannot be "common", "core" and "web" at the same time. Try:

```
def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll { it.name in ["common", "core", "web"] }
```

The condition now returns `true` if the name is any one of the strings in the list (that's what Groovy's `in` does).

Comment: Thanks it worked for me ! What have you try to do here? I'm not able to understand.. Can you add a bit more detail on this please.